# Hello, AJAX its not calculating my if conditions

Tags: php, ajax

Im making a AJAX form but i have a problem with validation, i need to make a condition when a input data is greater than a variable i define in the action file echo something out, but my condition is not working its always returning true, here is the code:

```
<?php

include "../../admin/includes/controller.php";
$msg = "";
$balance = "";
#Get stuff from form...

if(!empty($_POST)) {

#Define submited variables

$user = $_POST['user'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$asset = $_POST['asset'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$margin = $_POST['margin'];


#Check balance...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user';";
$result = $db->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $balance = $row['balance'];
}



This is the condition i want to check:

if ($balance > $margin) {
    $msg = "Trade opened successfully";
} else {
    $msg = "low balance";
}

#Print out message...
echo $msg;}
?>
```

This is my AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#open').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var asset = $('#asset').val();
        var amount = $('#amount').val();
        var margin = $('#margin').val();
        var user = $('#user').val();
        var type = $('#type').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "q/db.php",
            data: {
                "asset": asset,
                "amount": amount,
                "price": price,
                "type": type,
                "user": user,
                "margin": margin
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
                $('#contactform')[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the values of both $margin and $balance? Echo these values to see them. Quite easy to figure out.

Comment: but no with echo but var_dump because you need to know if both values are type numbers otherwise > operator will not work

Comment: @HanletEscaño yes i have tried this: 

if ($balance > $margin) {
   echo "$balance and $margin";
} else {
    $msg = "low balance";
}

and it printed out both.

Comment: @steven i understand, but what are the values? Because if $balance is in fact > than $margin, then the problem is not the if statement. Did you mean to break out of that while loop or something?

Comment: @HanletEscaño i fixed this, i changed if(!empty($_POST)) to if($margin> $balance) and its just as i needed, the form does not submit if the condition is true, thanks for ringing a bell to this i really appreciate, 4real thanks soo much.

Comment: @steven glad that you figured it out.